# Settings api in wordpress unable to save settings

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on the settings api of the wordpress but can't save the settings, as it returns nothing. I can't understand what am i doing wrong here. I am new to wordpress development so can't figure it out.

```
<?php    
    add_action( 'admin_init', function() {
    register_setting( 'my-plugin-settings', 'map_option_1' );

});

function my_plugin_page() {
  ?>
    <div class="wrap">
      <form action="admin.php?page=creww_dashboard" method="post">

        <?php
          settings_fields( 'my-plugin-settings' );
          do_settings_sections( 'my-plugin-settings' );
        ?>
        <table>

            <tr>
                <th>Api Key</th>
                <td><input type="text" placeholder="Your name" name="map_option_1" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('map_option_1') ); ?>" size="50" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><?php submit_button(); ?></td>
            </tr>

        </table>

      </form>
    </div>
  <?php
}

my_plugin_page();
```

Comment: You may have more help for that on the site for WordPress development questions : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: I believe you need to add a settings section first and add settings fields to that section.

https://alazierplace.com/2018/06/15/how-to-save-custom-settings-for-your-wordpress-plugin/